# Using multiple project template, how to include file from other project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

I'm creating multi-project template with the following structure

```
Project1\FolderA\ClassA.cs
Project1.DomainModel\ClassB.cs
```

I want to include ClassB.cs to Folder A in Project 1. Before the project is exported as template, this is how ClassB is linked to Project1\FolderA.

```
<Compile Include="..\Project1.DomainModel\ClassB.cs">
<Link>FolderA\ClassB.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

When exported as template, the above definition becomes:

```
<Compile Include="..\$safeprojectname$.DomainModel\ClassB.cs">
<Link>FolderA\ClassB.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

When I create new project using the template, ClassB path is broken because it refers to

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\gjyzk4ow.35l\NewProject1.DomainModel\ClassB.cs.
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit**: Do I need to implement IWizard for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Well, I created a wizard and replace it manually. It works for me.